# Prove that $\|T\|_{op}=\max\left\lbrace\sqrt {|\lambda_1|},\sqrt {|\lambda_2|},\dots,\sqrt {|\lambda_n|}\right\rbrace$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Definition:

Assume that $T$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $V'$ (which are two vector spaces having the inner products $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ and $\left\|\cdot\right\|'$ respectively).
Then, **The operational norm of $T$** is called $\|T\|_{op}$ and defined like this:

$$\|T\|_{op} := \sup\left\lbrace\|T(x)\|':\|x\| \le 1\right\rbrace.$$

---

Question:

Assume that $T(X)=AX$ (such that $A\in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb R)$).

Prove that:

> $\|T\|_{op}=\max\left\lbrace\sqrt {|\lambda_1|},\sqrt
>  {|\lambda_2|},\dots,\sqrt {|\lambda_n|}\right\rbrace$ such that
>   $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $A^tA$.

There are some hints provided with the question:

(i) If $B$ is a symmetric matrix, then eigenvalues of $B$ are real numbers.  (Assume that we know this)
(ii) All of the eigenvalues of $A^tA$ are not negative. (This is one of the steps of the proof.)
(iii) $\forall u,v \in \mathbb R^n \space\space \langle Au,v\rangle = \langle u,A^tv\rangle$ (I don't know how this is useful.)

So, We know that $A^tA$ is a symmetric matrix. Then, we conclude that  its eigenvalues are real numbers.

What next? It seems that I'm too far from the statement that the question wants to be proved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**
$$\|T(x) \|^2= (Ax) \cdot (Ax)= (Ax)^TAx=x^TA^TAx$$

Now,  orthogonality diagonalize $A^TA$. You have
$$A^TA=PDP^T$$ for an orthogonal matrix $P$.

Setting $Y =P^Tx$ you get 
$$\|T(x) \|^2=y^TDy=\lambda_1y_1^2+...+\lambda_n y_n^2$$

and, since $P$ is orthogonal you have
$$y_1^2+..+y_n^2=\| x \|^2$$

Comment: Thanks! Would u please explain how the last equation helps solving the problem? I can't see the way to reach the statement...

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade How can you relate $\lambda_1y_1^2+...+\lambda_n y_n^2$ to the maximum of $\lambda_1,.., \lambda_n$ and $y_1^2+..+y_n^2$?

Comment: Can i say the biggest tense is the one having the biggest absolute value of $\lambda$? I'm not sure because of the $y_i^2$'s...

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade Hint: each $\lambda_i$ is less or equal to the maximum...

Comment: Excuse me if i'm tooo stupid! I know that "each .... is less than or..." but how is this useful?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade Well, if $\lambda_1 \leq max$ then $\lambda_1y_1^2 \leq max \cdot y_1^2$. Now repeat....